# How can I hide or remove Multiwindow tray for my application, programmatically in android?

Tags: android

I am working on an application that needs to be opened in full screen. I am able to remove title bar & Action bar from my application. But multi-window tray icon appears on side of application. Please let me know how can I hide or remove that tray to appear.

Note: I neither want to go to setting & change the setting nor want to press & hold back button to disable it. I want the open should be disabled automatically whenever my app starts.

Comment: use full screen rather

Comment: @android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen is already used but this doesn't serve the purpose.

Comment: already tried with <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>  and it did not work